# TFS-DASHBOARD - Adding a Enlarge button a widget

Tags: javascript, iframe, tfs, sdk, widget

Hi i am using [Iframe Dashboard widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=areve.iframe-dashboard-widget) extension I configured it my self so it can be displayed in "6x6" format which doesn't work, unfortunetly TFS maximum widget size is 4x4 that is too small to show some of my work,How can i add a Enlarge button/function  to the widget?Some of TFS default widgets have that button.

This is my VSS configuration javascript.

```
VSS.init({
  explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
  usePlatformStyles: true
});

VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers"],
  function(WidgetHelpers) {
    WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
    VSS.register("IframeDashboardWidget", function() {
      var getServerStatus = function(widgetSettings) {
        var $iframe = $('#iframe');
        var settings = JSON.parse(widgetSettings.customSettings.data);
        if (settings && settings.url) {
          $iframe.attr("src", settings.url);
        } else {
          $iframe.attr("src", 'data:text/html,<html><body style="font:1.2em sans-serif;background-color:#008000;color:#ffffff;font:16px Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif"><div>Iframe</div><div>Dashboard</div><div>Widget</div></body></html>');
        }

        return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
      }

      return {
        load: function(widgetSettings) {
          $iframe.resizeTo();
          return getServerStatus(widgetSettings);
        },
        reload: function(widgetSettings) {
          return getServerStatus(widgetSettings);
        }
      }
    });
    VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
  });
```

Comment: Which  Enlarge button are you meaning ? Did you mean  the one in the side of configure button of the widget? It will pop-up a new window, not shows directly in the dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a  concept of supported size in the widget.

> **supportedSizes**
>
> Array of sizes supported by your widget. When a widget supports
>   multiple sizes, the first size in the array is the default size of the
>   widget. The widget size is specified in terms of the rows and columns
>   occupied by the widget in the dashboard grid. One row/column
>   corresponds to 160px. Any dimension above 1x1 will get an additional
>   10px that represent the gutter between widgets. For example, a 3x2
>   widget will be 160*3+10*2 wide and 160*2+10*1 tall. **The maximum
>   supported size is 4x4.**

More details please refer  this tutorial: [Add a dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget)

---

*Update*

You could try to use  [VSS.resize()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget) function, but it has the scroll bar. For example, VSS.resize(400,500) (before VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();).

Comment: Yes, i know out that concept, make my question a bit  clearer  : Is there a way to make the widget bigger than 4x4?

Comment: Hi @WojtekT Sorry for the misunderstanding. You could give a try to use [VSS.resize()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_resize) function, but it may has the scroll bar. For example, VSS.resize(400,500) (before VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();).

Comment: I tried but the only thing that actually resizes is the content within the frame. I guess this isn't possible hopefully someone will change the maximum size in TFS thanks anyway for you answers.

Comment: @WojtekT Did you also try to use some other browser such as chrome instead of IE. Someone said which works in chrome, not work in IE. After go through related APIs, roughly the same ideas with you.   However, there is a build-in widget called **markdown**, for that specific widget you could change the size big than 4X4 even full screen. It's hard to say you couldn't do this. Maybe the API or method is just not open source for now.